# ag-grid Angular "colDef.cellRendererFramework.component is deprecated"

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Since previous version of ag-grid we could pass a Component as a dependency into our cellRendererFramework like this:

```
{
    headerName: "Clickable Component",
    field: "name",
    cellRendererFramework: {
        component: ClickableParentComponent,
        dependencies: [ClickableComponent]
    },
    width: 200
}
```

this is an example taken from this [ag-grid blog](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular2-support-v7/).

Unfortunatelly version 9 gives me a deprecated warning about this:

```
colDef.cellRendererFramework.component is deprecated - please refer to https://ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/
```

Is there any recommended way now to achieve this? I couldn't find anything about this in ag-grid's changelogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the trick to communicate with the parent component is using the context object:

```js
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
    context: {
        componentParent: this
    }
};
```

Taken from [Simple Dynamic Component example](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-dynamic/#dynamic&gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 0):

did you miss this part of the blog?

> instead of:
>
> ```
> {
>     headerName: "Clickable Component",
>     field: "name",
>     cellRendererFramework: {
>         component: ClickableParentComponent,
>         dependencies: [ClickableComponent]
>     },
>     width: 200
> }
> ```
>
> You now only need to do this:
>
> ```
> {
>     headerName: "Clickable Component",
>     field: "name",
>     cellRendererFramework: ClickableParentComponent,
>     width: 250
> }
> ```

Comment: How do you pass in the dependency? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: As I understand it, you don't need to pass the dependency any more

Comment: The answer I am looking for is what is  currently the recommended way to pass dependency if not the one that is now deprecated. Telling me I don't have to do it really doesn't help.

Comment: The current recommendation seems to be very clear form their docs... take a look at the second example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-dynamic/#dynamic&gsc.tab=0)

Comment: At the second example there is no dependecy class passed in.How does the 'ClickableParentComponent' talks to 'ClickableComponent' then?

Comment: I am no angular guru... but it looks like there was a `module` created that gets wrapped into angular... Ag-grid only knows that it needs `ClickableParentComponent`, while angular knows about the module and the extra dependencies... perhaps [this page of the angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) sheds more light on the subject