# ag-grid angular2 cellRendererFramework no component factory found

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I tried to implement one of the following examples:

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular2-support/

```
colDef = {
    // instead of cellRenderer we use cellRendererFramework
    cellRendererFramework: {
        template: '{{params.value | currency}}',
        moduleImports: [CommonModule]
    },
    // specify all the other fields as normal
    headerName: "Currency Pipe Template",
    field: "value",
    width: 200
```

The import in the module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    .....
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
],
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you
>   add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>       at noComponentFactoryError (core.es5.js:3302) [angular]
>       at _NullComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.es5.js:3320) [angular]
>       at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.es5.js:3362) [angular]
>       at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.es5.js:3362) [angular]
>       at Ng2ComponentFactory.createComponent (ng2ComponentFactory.js:149) [angular]
>       at CellRenderer.createComponent (ng2ComponentFactory.js:47) [angular]
>       at CellRenderer.BaseGuiComponent.init (ng2ComponentFactory.js:167) [angular]
>       at CellRenderer.init (ng2ComponentFactory.js:34) [angular]
>       at CellRendererService.useCellRenderer (cellRendererService.js:49) [angular]
>       at RenderedCell.useCellRenderer (renderedCell.js:1009) [angular]
>       at RenderedCell.putDataIntoCell (renderedCell.js:957) [angular]
>       at RenderedCell.populateCell (renderedCell.js:784) [angular]
>       at RenderedCell.init (renderedCell.js:323) [angular]
>       at vendor.bundle.js:19006:115 [angular]

I get the same error with:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    .....
    AgGridModule.withComponents([CommonModule])
],
```

Or with:

```
colDef = {
    // instead of cellRenderer we use cellRendererFramework
    cellRendererFramework: {
        template: '{{params.value}}'
    },
    // specify all the other fields as normal
    headerName: "Currency Pipe Template",
    field: "value",
    width: 200

@NgModule({
      imports: [
        .....
        AgGridModule.withComponents([])
    ],
```

What is the correct module for the import or for the entryComponents??

Comment: Are you on ag-grid version 6.x? because from version 7 after [they changed how components are handled](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular2-support-v7/) Take a look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44025481/5187323)

Comment: This is another question and I use the newest version. I want to use a template in the CellRendererFramework and not a component (like in the question). To bind a component works in my project, but i want to use a template, for example for a pipe. I don't want to create a component, only for a pipe.